# Joining multiple sentences containing conjuction

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, compound-complex

I have a problem with joining these sentences.

Original sentence:

> I conducted two experiments. The first experiment was conducted using temperature at 70oC and liquid flow rate of 2 l/min. The second experiment was conducted using temperature at 30oC and liquid flow rate of 5 l/min.

I would like to make it into passive voice in one sentence.
I tried several ways:

> 1. Two experiments were conducted using temperature at 70oC and 30oC; liquid flow rate of 2 and 5 l/min.
> 2. Two experiments were conducted using temperature and liquid flow rate of 70oC and 2 l/min; 30oC and 5 l/min.
> 3. Two experiments, in which the temperature (48h and 24h) and liquid flow rate (10/65 and 20/55) were conducted.

All of them feel kind of strange though.
I don't know what is the grammatically correct way to do it. I guess it requires punctuation of semicolon or colon, but I have no idea how to use it correctly.

Comment: Your third example contains information quite different from the first two. But for the first two you might say: **Two experiments were conducted, one at a temperature of C70* and a liquid flow rate of 2l/min; the other at C30* and a (liquid) flow rate of 5l/min.** I don't follow what you are saying in example 3.

Comment: I guess you're trying to show a degree symbol, but it's usual practice in scientific contexts to write "C" without a degree symbol, so "70 C" would be much clearer. Also, I've no idea why the third version has temperatures in hours and different flow rates, is that supposed to be significant?

Answer (score 1):

None of your three examples is grammatical; among other issues, a colon is used to separate two complete sentences. (It can also be used to separate content containing commas in lists.) Here are some grammatical and unambiguous options frequently seen in technical writing:

- Two experiments were conducted at temperatures and liquid flow rates of 70°C and 2 l/min and 30°C and 5 l/min, respectively.
- Two experiments were conducted: one at a temperature and liquid flow rate of 70°C and 2 l/min and one at 30°C and 5 l/min, respectively.
- Two experiments were conducted with different temperature–liquid flow rate pairs: 70°C and 2 l/min and 30°C and 5 l/min.

Comment: I didn't know that it is possible to use multiple 'and' in one sentence. This is very helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: The multiple "and"s could be clarified with some punctuation. Or even better the OP could use two sentences (sometimes what the OP wants isn't best)